# Dynamic routing in flet python

Tags: python, dynamic-routing, flet

I want to build a chat app with `flet` in `python`.

For routing I defined a `Router` class which handles all the routing. But I am not able to figure a way out for implementing dynamic routes such as `"/:username"`.

How can I acheive dynamic routing in `flet` without introducing a third party dependency?

## `router.py`

```
import flet as ft

from routes.login import LoginPage
from routes.register import RegisterPage
from routes.home import HomePage
from routes.user_profile import UserProfilePage

class Router:
    def __init__(self, page: ft.Page):
        self.page = page
        self.routes = {
            "/login": LoginPage(page),
            "/register": RegisterPage(page),
            "/": HomePage(page),
            "/:username": UserProfilePage(page)
        }
        self.body = ft.Container(
            content=self.routes["/login"]
        )

    def change_route(self, event: ft.RouteChangeEvent):
        self.body.content = self.routes[event.route]
        self.body.content.init_page()
        self.page.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find this community package ([flet-route](https://github.com/saurabhwadekar/flet_route)) very useful when dealing with - complex - routing in flet.
It has no additional requirement... just Flet (the `repath` lib mentioned in its repo is actually a Flet requirement).